# how do I remove every single custom bone shape from a project

Tags: armature

I have downloaded a project with an armature that uses custom object shapes for most of the bones. I do not want any of these. Going through each bone and removing them is very time consuming. How do I remove all of them at once.

Answer (score 1):

In *Pose* mode, select all the bones, open the *Bone panel > Viewport Display > Custom Shape*, press <kbd>Alt</kbd> when you press on the X button and it will remove the custom shapes for all the bones.